# ASP.NET navbar link oddity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to asp.net. I am producing a website were people can register as either an individual or a company. To do this I started with a new MVC app with User Authentication enabled.

In AccountController I added:

```
public ActionResult Register(string id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

In the Register view I added:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register as individual", "Register/Individual", "Account")
@Html.ActionLink("Register as company", "Register/Company", "Account")
```

I also added two more views (Individual and Company).

This all works as expected, however, the Register link in the top navbar is acting odd.

If I am on the home page, it will take me to Account/Register as expected
If I then click on the individual link (so the route is Account/Register/Individual) the Register link in the navbar will navigate to the same route (Account/Register/Individual)
The same happens with company.

I'd like it to go back to Account/Register. The Razor code for it is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Here you are trying to explicitly pass empty string as the parameter value for the `Register` action method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new { id =""}, 
                                                       new { id = "registerLink" })
```

Also replace your links in register view like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register as individual", "Register", "Account", 
                                     new { id ="Individual"},null)
@Html.ActionLink("Register as company", "Register", "Account",
                                     new { id ="Company"},null)
```